# How does // double slash in the middle of a URL change the expected file location?

Tags: url

When google crawls my website it finds a file "https://www.aizhu.com/BIBLE/GB/HB//11.HTM" with double slash and gives many errors. Where is Google looking to find this file with the double slash (//)?
I have seached my directory (using FileZilla) and cannot find this file anywhere.
(The correct Url is "https://www.aizhu.com/BIBLE/GB/HB/11.HTM" with a single slash and gives no errors.)
.